# jquery mobile custom loading message does not show until time to close it

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use the loading widget to show when some time consuming work is being done on my page.  I modified the code on the demo page (), it works except for when I add a function call to the .onclick, it will not show up until after the called function is completed, which defeats the purpose entirely.

```
$('#fstart').on('click', function(e) {       
    $.mobile.loading( "show", {
            text: 'Processing Schedule File.',
            textVisible: 'true',
            theme: 'a',
            textonly: false
    });
            /* The loading window is closed by the called function */
    handleProcessing();
})
```

What do I need to do to get the loading widget to pop up when I call it?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Are you using a web-kit browser like Chrome or Safari?

Comment: @Gajotres - Sorry, forgot to add that this works in FF, but not Chrome or IE.

Comment: Excellent, let me write you an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, when working with web-kit browsers, you must use **setTimeout** or **serInterval** to trigger jQuery Mobile AJAX loader.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show',{ text:msg, textVisible:true, theme:'b', textonly:text_only});
}, 1);
```

One milisecond is enough. Also take a look at my older **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519546/dont-hide-loader-till-the-page-loads-completely-in-jquery-mobile/16520313#16520313)**, or **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059604/jquerymobile-display-loading-animation-spinner-while-loading-page/16060429#16060429)** one. You will find working examples in my older answers. Usually I would close this question as a duplicate but I was not active here since last year and that was also a time I list so this problem.

So please be kind and tell me if this solution solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is working in FF, Chrome and on the Android tablet they'll be using.  It still isn't working in IE11, but that isn't a concern for this project.